# What does it take to unlock the Deceiver trait?

Tags: pandemic-2

I'm trying to get my disease to stay under the radar as much as possible, and would like to leverage the Deceiver trait to do so. However it would seem I need to achieve some mark before I am even allowed to unlock it. What's the mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GameFAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/iphone/669504-pandemic-25/wiki/2-1-stealth-walkthrough), Deceiver is unlocked if you get to

`50,000,000 with no deaths.`